# AngularJS set width using ng-style

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'd like to dynamically resize a div when an event from S3 is fired.

In the following code I send the `progress` variable to the `updateProgress` function as a param. This function is in the highest scope of my Angular controller.

```
s3.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
        var progress;
        progress = Math.floor(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
        updateProgress(progress);
    })
    .send(function(err, res, data) {
        if (err) {
            growl.error("We're having trouble uploading your image. Please try again!", {title: 'Whoops!', ttl: 5000});
            console.log('Error uploading' + err);
        } else {
            imgLocation = res.Location;
            postToFirebase(imgLocation);
        }
    });
```

Here's my updateProgress function

```
function updateProgress(percent) {
    $scope.progressBar = {
        'width': percent + '%'
    }
}
```

HTML

`<div ng-style="progressBar" class="shot__image--post__progress"></div>`

I can successfully console.log the AWS event and the progress value. However, when I upload the image the width never changes.

Comment: Where did you put your `console.log`? Did you checked it inside `function updateProgress(percent)`?

Comment: I checked the `console.log` from the updateProgress function and it's logging the correct values. Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/GXdNt

Comment: @cole Roberts, put debugger in `updateProgress` method and observe the value of `percent`. If possible you can add Fiddle/Plnkr.

Comment: @KhalidHussain I have done this. Please see my above comment. The value(s) are correct when being passed to the function.

Comment: Assuming the `s3` library is not part of or privy to the Angular digest cycle, you need to wrap the changes to `$scope` properties in `$scope.$apply` or `$scope.$applyAsync`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply. User [Raghu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1117861/raghu) answered this earlier but was downvoted for some reason

Comment: @ColeRoberts Why don't you add fiddle/plnkr? In fiddle, you don't need to call actual `s3`, just call a dummy method.

Comment: @Phil I didn't downvote him, I'm not sure why he was downvoted.

Comment: @Phil That was it! I was unaware of the need for the $apply method in this case.

Comment: @ColeRoberts maybe find some other good answers from Raghu and give them an upvote

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Phil in the comments of this thread.

> Assuming the s3 library is not part of or privy to the Angular digest
>   cycle, you need to wrap the changes to $scope properties in
>   $scope.$apply or $scope.$applyAsync. See
>   docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply. User Raghu
>   answered this earlier but was downvoted for some reason

The solution was to simply call `$scope.$apply()` within the `updateProgress` fn.